# How can I prove ($number \ of\ verticies \over size \ of\ maximum\ independent \ set$ ) $\leq$ chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How can I prove 
$$n/ \beta(G) \leq \chi(G)$$ .

I thought of using an algorithm that selects a maximum independent set and gives them a color and etc. but this does not necessarily give a minimum coloring.

Is this inequality even true?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, an optimal coloring of the vertices cannot use more than $\chi(G)$ independent sets of size $\alpha(G)$ (the order of the largest independent set that you call $\beta(G)$). More formally, consider an optimal coloring, and let $S_k$ be the $\chi(G)$ independent sets of this coloring.
$$
V=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\chi(G)}S_k,
$$
Since, the independent sets are pairwise disjoint, and that $|S_k|\le \alpha(G)$ for all $k$:
$$
n=\sum_{k=1}^{\chi(G)}|S_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^{\chi(G)}\alpha(G) = \chi(G)\alpha(G)
$$
which yields
$$
\chi(G)\ge \frac{n}{\alpha(G)}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\frac{n}{\beta(G)}>\chi(G)$. We start by considering a $\chi(G)$-coloring of $G$. Its existence is guaranteed by the definition of chromatic number.

In particular, every monochromatic set, that is, sets of vertices that are assigned the same color, is an independent set, and has size no more than $\beta(G)$.

Consequently, $n=\sum_c(\text{# of vertices with color }c)\leq\beta(G)\chi(G)<n$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: the proof could be easily turned into a direct proof rather than a proof by contradiction .  i would be nice to see the direct proof .